# sql - how to query member of group with recursion (1 table with user and groups)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Following structure exists:

```
CREATE TABLE rel(
  entry_id int,
  parent_id int
  )

CREATE TABLE entries(
  entry_id int,
  name varchar(44)
)
```

Following data exists:

```
INSERT INTO entries VALUES (1,'user 1');
INSERT INTO entries VALUES (2,'group 2');
INSERT INTO entries VALUES (3,'group 3');
INSERT INTO entries VALUES (4,'user 4');
INSERT INTO entries VALUES (5,'user 5');

INSERT INTO rel VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO rel VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO rel VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO rel VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO rel VALUES (2,NULL);
```

Result should look like:

```
group_id| group_name | member_id | member_name | level
2       | group 2    |   4       |  user 4     |  0
2       | group 2    |   1       |  user 1     |  1
2       | group 2    |   5       |  user 5     |  1
3       | group 3    |   1       |  user 1     |  0
3       | group 3    |   5       |  user 5     |  0
```

I already tried stuff like the following but it's not returning the results I need:

```
SELECT 
  entries.entry_id, 
  entries.name, 
  rel.parent_id,
  (SELECT name FROM entries WHERE entry_id=parent_id) AS parent_name
INTO 
  #tmpEntries 
FROM
  entries, rel
WHERE
  rel.entry_id = entries.entry_id
;

SELECT * FROM #tmpEntries;

WITH MyCTE
AS ( 
  SELECT 
  entry_id, 
  name, 
  parent_id,
  --CAST('' AS VARCHAR(44)) AS 
  parent_name
FROM #tmpEntries 
--WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    #tmpEntries.entry_id, 
    #tmpEntries.name, 
    #tmpEntries.parent_id, 
    --MyCTE.name AS 
  #tmpEntries.parent_name
FROM #tmpEntries 
INNER JOIN MyCTE ON #tmpEntries.parent_id = MyCTE.entry_id
--WHERE #tmpEntries.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
--  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT entry_id FROM rel WHERE parent_id=#tmpEntries.entry_id)
   )
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM MyCTE
ORDER BY parent_id
;

WITH MyCTE2
AS ( 
  SELECT 
  entry_id, 
  name, 
  parent_id,
  --CAST('' AS VARCHAR(44)) AS 
  parent_name
FROM #tmpEntries 
--WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    #tmpEntries.entry_id, 
    #tmpEntries.name, 
    #tmpEntries.parent_id, 
    --MyCTE.name AS 
  #tmpEntries.parent_name
FROM #tmpEntries 
INNER JOIN MyCTE2 ON #tmpEntries.parent_id = MyCTE2.entry_id
--WHERE #tmpEntries.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT entry_id FROM rel WHERE parent_id=#tmpEntries.entry_id)
   )
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM MyCTE2
ORDER BY parent_id
```

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server. I re-tagged the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work under assumption that group is anything that contains one or more members i.e. empty group will be considered a simple member.

```
with cte_hierarchy as
(
  select entry_id, parent_id, 0 as level
  from rel
  where parent_id is not null

  union all

  select h.entry_id, rel.parent_id, h.level + 1 as level
  from cte_hierarchy h
  inner join rel on h.parent_id = rel.entry_id
)
select 
  g.entry_id as group_id,
  g.name as group_name,
  e.entry_id as member_id,
  e.name as member_name,
  h.level
from cte_hierarchy h
inner join entries e on e.entry_id = h.entry_id
inner join entries g on g.entry_id = h.parent_id
where not exists (select * from rel where parent_id = h.entry_id)
order by g.entry_id, h.level, e.entry_id
```

The where clause excludes nested groups that would otherwise appear as members.